# Lift due to air flowing above wings

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I was wondering that why air (or any other medium) flowing above the surface of any object produce some lift.Well i know the mathematical equation for it given by bernoulli theorem in which we can easily see that increase in velocity of air decrease the air pressure there and hence a low pressure region is created and then lift is produced.But apart from equation how can we imagine that increasing air velocity decrases the air pressure there

Comment: In order for lift to occur there also need to be a forward force like a propeller or jet engine to provide energy.

Comment: Ok let us assume their is some forward force then what

Comment: As Mike says below he talks about momentum changes and the pressure changes.  It's complex, and pressure is quantity of a particles, so there must be fewer on top of the wing.  If there are fewer than the ones below are able to lift.

Answer (score 2):

The Bernoulli argument is precisely backwards. The wing deflects the air stream downwards. Newton's third law applied the the change in momentum of the air produces low pressure over the wing and higher pressure below the wing. The low pressure speeds up the air  as it enters the low pressure zone above the wing, and the high pressure below the wing  slows own the air there.

Of course all this can be expressied  mathematically via the Kutta-Joukowski theorem and the shedding of starting vortices.

Comment: How the air diflected downwards can change the pressure above the wing

Comment: @sourabh The air above the wing is also being deflected downwards. If it were not, there would be a vacuum "shadow" above the wing. The air moves downwards to fill the "shadow" being sucked in by the lower pressure.

Comment: @Sourabh: If I can expand on mike stone's answer, it's important to understand that the wing induces [*circulation*](https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-circulation). The extra velocity on the top surface is part of that circulation (also called "bound vortex"). Without the circulation, there is no lift. In particular, do not assume the air above has to meet up with the air below, with the shape of the wing making it travel farther. It does not meet up with the air below. The shape of the wing is not essential to this, it is only an optimization.